# number of morphemes in "liver"

Tags: morphemes, cranberry-morphemes

So my understanding is that all morphemes are either "free" morphemes (can exist on their own as words with meaning) or "bound" morphemes (can't exist on their own as words, which means that every bound morpheme is thus some type of affix).

So what about the word LIVER then? We can separate the word LIVER into "live" (which can stand by itself as a word with meaning, and hence fulfills the requirement of a free morpheme) plus "er" (a universally recognized suffix), but neither "live" nor "er" have any *lexical* relationship to LIVER.  So is correct to say that LIVER consists of the two morphemes "live" (free) + "er" (bound), or is liver a one-morpheme word? My suspicion is no, it's a one-morpheme word, but I wanted to get some experts to confirm...

Comment: If you mean _liver_ the body organ, no, that's its own morpheme, like _heart_ or _stomach_. The fact that it ends in _er_ is irrelevant. So do _river_ and _tiger_, for instance. If you don't mean the body organ, I don't understand what you do mean.

Comment: Hi John... Yes, I'm referring to the organ.  RIVER and TIGER would be partially, but not completely, analogous because when you separate the "er" in TIGER or RIVER, the rest of the word ("tig" and "riv") is not a free morpheme, whereas when you separate the "er" from LIVER, you *are* left with a free morpheme (albeit one which has no lexical relation to LIVER)...

Comment: We don't begin sentences with *So* in formal writing, even less new paragraphs, or whole new posts. So!

Comment: @Kris This isn't formal writing.

Comment: When you separate _er_ from _liv_, you don't get the morpheme _live_. You don't get any morpheme at all. _Liver, tiger,_ and _river_ are all one morpheme each, inseparable morphologically. And not all root morphemes occur as free morphemes; many are "cranberry morphs" that only occur in compounds or with other morphology, like the _cran_ part of _cranberry_.

Comment: @Araucaria This is ELU. Not even [ell.se] :)

Comment: @JohnLawler Closer home, *other*?

Comment: _Other_ originally was the comparative form of _and_ (in German it's _ander_), and the comparative suffix is a genuine inflectional morpheme. Of course that doesn't mean it still is a separate morpheme here. _Other_ does use _than_ (e.g, _other than those_), which is restricted to comparatives . So maybe there's still a joint in _oth-er_; but clearly the root it's attached to isn't a free morpheme.

Answer (score 2):

Liver, tiger and river are one morpheme each.

As per comments:

> Liver, tiger, and river are all one morpheme each, inseparable morphologically. And not all root morphemes occur as free morphemes; many are "cranberry morphs" that only occur in compounds or with other morphology, like the cran part of cranberry. - [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler)