# What expression should I use to indicate that one felt comfortable in a new place after initially feeling uncomfortable?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I have a new friend and he is a new comer here. He needs to adapt to the culture here. Last week he told me that he felt uncomfortable.  Yesterday, he said that he felt at home. He has been two weeks here.

My question is, how do I say, "he finally felt comfortable here"? Is there any idiomatic expression? I checked in a dictionary and found: *feel at home*

Comment: Felt at home works.

Comment: You could say "He feels that he is settling in."

Comment: Also: he accommodated himself.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on Kate Bunting's comment.

> After some initial anxiety, yesterday, two weeks after arriving, my
>   new friend finally admitted to settling in.

TFD:

> > **[settle in](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/settle+in)**
> >     *v.*
> >     To become established or comfortable in a new environment or circumstance:
> >     It took a month for us to settle in after the move.
> >     We'll come visit you after you get settled in.
> >
> > The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs. Copyright © 2005
> >     by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton
> >     Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.

Comment: CW wouldn't be the worst idea when making an answer this way.

Comment: @Helmar, can you please clarify? What is CW?

Comment: Community Wiki. There's a check box if you edit your answer. This is one: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333406/number-of-morphemes-in-liver/347934#347934 It's used when  answering with someone else's comment after a time to provide an answer that can be accepted without seeming to *steal* since you won't get any reputation. Another use is to invite other people to contribute to the same answer.

Comment: @Helmar, thanks for this. I have edited the answer to make it CW.